# vendor directory not being used to resolve imports on go build

Tags: go, dependency-management, glide-golang

I'm in the process of relearning Go. I installed the latest Go version (`1.7.1`) using [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) and I am looking to build a simple rest api app using [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin). I installed it using `glide get https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin` ([glide](https://glide.sh/)) and that created a "vendor" folder on my project root. Running my app though, `go run main.go`, I encounter this error

```
main.go:3:8: cannot find package "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" in any of:
    /home/yowmamasita/.gvm/gos/go1.6.3/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOROOT)
    /home/yowmamasita/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6.3/global/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOPATH)
```

It is not resolving the "vendor" directory glide just created

```
.
├── glide.lock
├── glide.yaml
├── main.go
├── README.md
└── vendor
    └── github.com
        └── gin-gonic
            └── gin
```

Not sure what's happening here, I thought after 1.5, it should be able to resolve imports from "vendor" directories without doing anything. I even added my projects folder on my `$GOPATH`

`/home/yowmamasita/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.7.1/global:/home/yowmamasita/goprojects`

What am I doing wrong here? I tried 1.6.3 too and I get the same error.

Comment: What is the output of `go env` and `go version`?

Comment: @putu https://ghostbin.com/paste/ayebv

Comment: The folder `/home/yowmamasita/goprojects` is not in your `GOPATH`. After modifying `GOPATH` variable, make sure to run `source .bashrc` or `source .bash_profile` or simply start a new terminal.

Comment: @putu you mean this line doesn't mean anything `GOPATH="/home/yowmamasita/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.7.1/global:/home/yowmamasita/goprojects"`?

Comment: It wasn't in the `ghostbin.com/paste/ayebv`. If you run `go run main.go` now, did you still get the error?

Comment: @putu weird, I copy-pasted that from there. Anyway, yes, still getting the error

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't read it correctly. [This issue](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/issues/167) may help. In short, you should put your project root inside `$GOPATH/src/`.

Comment: @putu can you please put this as an answer? This solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure:

1. Add the workspace (`/home/yowmamasita/goprojects`) to `$GOPATH` variable.
2. Typically under workspace there will be three directories which are `bin`, `pkg` and `src`. [More details](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)
3. You can omit `pkg` and `bin`, but the project which is using `vendor` packages or your custom package must be placed under `$GOPATH/src`, otherwise `go` compiler will not recognized it.

More discussions can be found [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14566) and [here](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/issues/167)

The structure should look like:

```
 $GOPATH
 └── src
     └── YOURPROJECT1
            ├── source codes #1
            └── vendor/

     └── YOURPROJECT2
            ├── source codes #2
            └── vendor/
```